# T and # symbol in xcode editor

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

What does the T symbol in Xcode editor's autocomplete for C++ code mean? This shows up while typing "INT_STAT" in the editor. I also see a hash symbol coe up while typing "INT_LEAST64_MIN" and was wondering what that meant as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

T is for `typedef` and I imagine # is for `#define`.